# How will I be able to senda ctrl + c in tcl

Tags: tcl

Is there a way that I could send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal a `tcl` program?

I am having a `tcl code` in which when I execute it, internally it should undergo through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal and print something like:

puts "sent ctrl+c" within the same file.

```
proc abc {                                 

         # Want to sent ctrl + c"
         Here I want the command for ctrl+c
         puts " sent ctrl+c"
}
```

Comment: `\003` is the ascii code for ctrl+c. But what do you mean by "send" ctrl+c? Send to what? Are you (or should you be) using expect?

Answer (score 5):

If you are sending the signal to a program under the control of Expect, you do:

```
send "\003"
```

That's literally the character that your keyboard generates immediately when you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>; it gets translated into a signal by the terminal driver.

*Otherwise,* you need to use the TclX package (or Expect, though you should only use that if you need its full capabilities) which provides a `kill` command:

```
package require Tclx

kill SIGINT $theProcessID
# You could also use INT or 15 to specify the signal to send.
# You can provide a list of PIDs instead of just one too.
```

Knowing what process ID to send to is a matter of keeping track of things when you create the process. The current process's PID is returned by the `pid` command if you don't give it any arguments. The process ID(s) of the subprocesses created are returned by `exec ... &` for all the (known) processes in the background pipeline it creates. For pipelines created with `open |...`, pass the channel handle for the pipeline to the `pid` command to get the subprocess IDs.

```
set pipeline [open |[list program1 ... | program2 ... | program3 ...] "r+"]
puts $pipeline "here is some input"
set outputLine [gets $pipeline]

kill SIGINT [pid $pipeline]

# This close *should* probably produce errors; you've killed the subprocesses after all
catch {close $pipeline}
```

---

If you're *handling* the interrupt signal, use the `signal` command from TclX to do it:

```
package require Tclx

signal error SIGINT;    # Generate a normal Tcl error on signal
signal trap SIGINT {;   # Custom signal handler
    puts "SIGNALLED!"
    exit
}
signal default SIGINT;  # Restore default behaviour
```

If you use `signal error SIGINT`, the error generated will have this message “`SIGINT signal received`” and this error code “`POSIX SIG SIGINT`”. This is easy to test for (especially with Tcl 8.6's `try … trap …` command).